# Point existing YAsnippet mode to a new filetype

Tags: emacs, bottle, yasnippet

I am running through the Bottle tutorial, and the YAsnippet mode for HTML would get me a large share of the productivity bonuses I am used to when crafting Bottle template files (`.tpl`).

Is there a way to tell YAsnippet to look at the existing entries under `html-mode` when opening filetypes of the extension `.tpl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution: associate `tpl` files with `html-mode`:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\'" . html-mode))
```

Another: copy the directory `html-mode` in snippets to a directory which has the same name as the mode you use for `tpl` files.

Answer (score 7):

Given that the Bottle template files are in `bottle-mode`, create a file in your `snippets` folder: `/my/snippets/bottle-mode/.yas-parents` with this as contents:

```
html-mode
```

This will make yasnippet load html-mode snippets for bottle-mode.

Comment: Couldn't find anything for `bottle-mode`...ended up going with another solution.

Comment: FYI @Droogans it's assumed that you'd create the folder `bottle-mode` where you keep your user defined snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is simpler then others, but what I did: created a symlink with the name of the target mode pointing to the snippets directory of the source mode. Eg:

```bsh
$ ln -s ~/.emacs.d/yasnippets/js-mode ~/.emacs.d/yasnippets/javascript-mode
```